# How can I ask R to flag a specific pattern (i.e., column value changes from 1 to 0) each time it occurs within a group of observations?

Tags: r, dplyr, pattern-matching, tidyverse, case-when

The below reprex mimics my data: for each person, I have different values of 'res' at different times. I need an indicator variable ('flag') to tell me each time that 'res' changes from 1 to 0 within a given person, and I want 'flag' to equal 1 at the first time (and the first time *only*) that 'res'= 0 after 'res' = 1. Lastly, I want to count the number of times 'flag' = 1 for each person.

My code has two problems:

1. It flags every time after 'res'= 1 that 'res' = 0 (but I need 'flag'= 1 *only* the first time 'res'=0).
2. Counting the number of times 'flag' = 1 does not work.

Note: The last 'res_next_time' is inevitably NA. By definition in my data, I would never have 'flag'=1 here, so it's okay that it defaults to 0.

Thanks for your help!

```r
#Load packages
library(Hmisc)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:Hmisc':
#> 
#>     src, summarize
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.5

#Create data set
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
time <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
res <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

#Populate data frame
d <- cbind(person, time, res)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

#Create new variable equal to 'res' at the person's next time point
d$res_next_time <- Lag(d$res, -1)

#Group times by person
d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
#Create a new variable 'flag' = 1 when a person's 'res' changes from 1 to 0, and 'flag' = 0 otherwise
  mutate(flag = case_when(res_next_time < 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
#Because 'flag'= 1 is at the time of 'res'= 1 before 'res'= 0, we lag it to have 'flag' = 1 at 'res' = 0
  mutate(flag_res0 = Lag(flag, +1)) %>%
#Replace the NAs in 'flag_res0' with 0
  replace_na(list(flag_res0 = 0)) %>%
  #mutate(flag_res0 = as.numeric(flag_res0 & cumsum(flag_res0) <= 1)) %>%
#Count number of flags per person
  mutate(mig_freq = sum(flag_res0)) %>%
#Limit the data to only include the final indicator
  select('person', 'time', 'res', 'flag_res0')
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>    person  time   res flag_res0
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1      1     1     1         0
#>  2      1     2     0         1
#>  3      1     3     1         0
#>  4      2     1     1         0
#>  5      3     2     1         0
#>  6      3     1     0         1
#>  7      3     2     0         1
#>  8      3     3     1         0
#>  9      3     4     0         1
#> 10      3     5     1         0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need the column `res_next_time` with my solution. I think that @Paul PR's is more concise.

```
# using your data d
d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(flag2 = if_else(lag(res) == 1 & res == 0 &  
                           !(duplicated(lag(res) == 1 & res == 0)),1, 0, 0))
```

You could add `ungroup()` at the end. That might be important depending on what's next. This basically is 'if TRUE TRUE and not duplicated, then...'

[image]

Your comment indicated that you aren't looking for the first occurrence but any occurrence within the group.

That's actually much simpler.

```
(d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(lag(res) == 1 & res == 0, 1, 0, 0)))
```

The output looks like this. (I added data at the end of your example data to show my occurrences.)

```
# # A tibble: 13 x 4
# # Groups:   person [3]
#    person  time   res  flag
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1      1     1     1     0
#  2      1     2     0     1
#  3      1     3     1     0
#  4      2     1     1     0
#  5      3     2     1     0
#  6      3     1     0     1
#  7      3     2     0     0
#  8      3     3     1     0
#  9      3     4     0     1
# 10      3     5     1     0
# 11      3     6     0     1
# 12      1     7     1     0
# 13      1     8     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you, Kat, this is SO close. Last problem: when a person (like person 3) has res change from 1 to 0 a second time, this solution doesn't flag the second time (whereas my code repeats 'flag = 1 for each subsequent 'res'=0. I need it to flag each time res changes from 1 to 0, regardless of if it's within the same person or not. Grateful for help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that solves the problem in two steps:

1. Use dplyr's `lag` function to calculate the previous value of res, rather than the next value of res. We do this in the grouped data frame so the first value of `res_last_time` is NA for each person.
2. Use `cumsum` in the grouped data frame to only keep the first flag = 1 for each person.

```r
d %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    mutate(res_last_time = lag(res, 1)) %>%
    mutate(flag = res == 0 & res_last_time == 1) %>%
    mutate(flag = as.numeric(flag & cumsum(flag) <= 1))
```

Using your same `d` data.frame, here are the results I get:

```r
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>    person  time   res res_last_time  flag
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      1     1     1            NA     0
#>  2      1     2     0             1     1
#>  3      1     3     1             0     0
#>  4      2     1     1            NA     0
#>  5      3     2     1            NA     0
#>  6      3     1     0             1     1
#>  7      3     2     0             0     0
#>  8      3     3     1             0     0
#>  9      3     4     0             1     0
#> 10      3     5     1             0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Paul PR. This is close, but: when a person (like person 3) has res change from 1 to 0 a second time, this solution doesn't flag the second time (whereas my code repeats 'flag = 1 for each subsequent 'res'=0. I need it to flag each time res changes from 1 to 0, regardless of if it's within the same person or not. Grateful for help!